# How much money did this Evil advertising promotion cost the Network?

Tags: commercial, evil

Being a pretty big fan of Robert & Michelle King's TV series, I also watch their latest venture, *Evil* on CBS.

The series is about examining evil in the world in various forms, as the characters of the show explore cases that may be scientifically or psychologically explainable, while also occasionally suggesting that their may be demonic and/or supernatural forces at work too!

But today, as I was looking for [the latest articles](https://wtvr.com/2020/01/28/heres-why-a-demon-bid-666-on-the-price-is-right/) on the series, I came across one about an advertising gimmick.

> A contestant dressed as a black demon appeared to make an appearance
>   on the “The Price Is Right” Monday and Tuesday, causing confusion for
>   viewers and sparking questions on social media.
>
> The demon was on the set of the game show and bid $666, which is
>   commonly associated with Satan and known as the devil’s number.
>
> It turns out, the demon was actually part of a commercial and an
>   advertisement for the CBS show “Evil.”

From CBS 6 in Denver, Colorado, one of *Evil's* alleged demonic characters, George, was a contestant on the TV game show, *The Price is Right*, where he bids a dollar more than the women next to him, accumulating to the number $666!

I was just wonder how much did this stint cost the network?

Comment: Do I understand right, that they - CBS - advertised their own programme on a quiz show also broadcast on CBS? If so, I would imagine the actual material cost to be negligible. Or are you talking about cost in terms of things like lost viewers, negative media coverage, complaints, law suits (which I'm sure they would be at least one of, given this is America we're talking about) etc?

Comment: No you understand correctly. I was talking about the actual material cost of doing it! :)

Comment: This is also not the only show they did this on either. They also featured George again as a bartender during a scene in Young and the Restless, but I decided I was more curious about this specific crossover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: the scene]

The scene in question, I was quite surprised at how professional the costume actually was.

With that said, it appears the actual material cost is being asked, and not some kind of cross over licensing deal, since The show ‘Evil’ and ‘The Price is Right’ both belong to CBS.

According to the [internet](https://www.makeupartistedu.org/california/california-salary/), make up artists can make anywhere from 30k, to 100k per year depending on skill.

While camera operators, and tv actors, monster actors/puppeteers and the like are often paid per show or gig depending on union rules, this can range up to 100k per year or so.

As for the material cost itself, the make up and costuming, from my crappy movie making days could range into 1000~ USD.

Depending on how much was on hand already, and if you would include employee wages for the stunt itself, scheduling, a writer, getting audiences etc. This could have cost CBS anywhere from 2000USD at the minimum to 50k.

Its mostly impossible to know beyond doing some [fermi estimates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem), or being the accountant who did the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'll probably be checking it off as "thee" answer if no one else comes up with anything else! :)